# How to trigger a PowerBI Datamart refresh from Azure Synapse Pipelines?

Tags: powerbi, azure-synapse, powerbi-api

Currently we are able to trigger an automated refresh of PowerBI datasets with an activity in Synapse Pipelines leveraging PowerBI API.

Is it possible by any chance to do the same with a PowerBI Datamart? Couldn't find any reference for this scenario.
The PowerBI Datamart source is a dedicated sql pool on the same Synapse workspace.

Thank you for your kind help.